# FindRoot with Grad

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find a numeric solution using Grad. 
With Solve, I get

```
Clear[m, x, x1, x2, f, fi];
m = 2;
x = Array[xi, m];
f = Array[fi, m];
fi[i_] := xi[i] - 1/i xi[i]^2;
sol = Solve[Grad[f, x] == 0, x]
```

> `{{xi[1] -> 1/2, xi[2] -> 1}}`

But with FindRoot, I get:

```
xo = x /. sol[[1]];
FindRoot[Grad[f, x] == 0, {x, xo}]
```

> `FindRoot[Grad[f,x] == 0, {x, xo}]`

How can fix the last command to get a solution?

Comment: Maybe like this:FindRoot[{Flatten@Grad[f, x][[1, 1]] == 0, 
  Flatten@Grad[f, x][[2, 2]] == 0}, {{xi[1], 1}, {xi[2], 1}}]

Answer (score 1):

```
  Clear[m, x, x1, x2, f, fi];
  m = 2;
  x = Array[xi, m];
  f = Array[fi, m];
  fi[i_] := xi[i] - 1/i xi[i]^2;
  sol = Solve[Grad[f, x] == 0, x]

  FindRoot[Flatten[Table[Grad[f, x][[n, n]] == 0, {n, 1, m}]], 
  Table[{xi[n], 1}, {n, 1, m}]]
```

> `{xi[1] -> 0.5, xi[2] -> 1.}`

For very large `m` you can use a `RandomInteger[]` or `RandomReal[]` randomize searches starting  points x=x0.

```
  FindRoot[Flatten[Table[Grad[f, x][[n, n]] == 0, {n, 1, m}]],
  Table[{xi[n], Evaluate@RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}, {n, 1, m}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = 2;
x = Array[xi, m];
f = Array[fi, m];
fi[i_] := xi[i] - 1/i xi[i]^2;
sol = Solve[Grad[f, x] == 0, x]
(* {{xi[1] -> 1/2, xi[2] -> 1}} *)

xo = x /. sol[[1]];

FindRoot[Cases[Flatten@Grad[f, x], Except[0]] == 0, Thread@{x, xo}]
```

> `{xi[1] -> 0.5, xi[2] -> 1.}`